# Extra google maps buttons on ipad doing nothing

Tags: iframe, google-maps, ipad

I'm using a Google maps iframe to display the location of my customer on his webpage. Works fine, but when viewed on Ipad the Google server apparently sends a different version of the maps. It looks like this:

[image]

Now, that wouldn't be a problem, but the two buttons on the bottom (i marked them in red), which I'm assuming are supposed to allow routing or something, don't do anything when being clicked?!

Has anyone an idea what my problem here might be? And how I either get those buttons to work (preferred solution) or else get them to disappear?

Comment: Is there a way for you to view the source code and inspect those elements from your iPad? I think Chrome is available for iPad's if so and it has the developer tool, you should check if there is a problem with z-index and if some page element is over them not allowing them to be clicked.

Comment: I'll have to take a look, but I doubt that that is the problem, as they do an "activated" animation when pushed (well, at least the left one does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of them by reducing size (height) of your iFrame and adding `overflow:hidden` style.

They don't work for me either. I seen this bug. But it's not the first time Google screws something on mobile devices (Google News for example somehow thinks my PC is a Tablet), so I wouldn't worry about that too much. Eventually hopefully they'll figure it out.